# Will there be a focus on creating a dockable On Screen Keyboard for Unity?

Tags: unity, multi-touch, tablet, ubuntu-touch

I have been looking for a couple of years for a clean, usable On Screen Keyboard for touchscreen interfaces for Ubuntu, and most have fallen short. With the increase interest in tablets and netbooks, is a project for improvement on your radar?

Comment: whats wrong with the gnome one?

Answer (score 1):

During the Gnome 2010 Boston summit there was a whole session dedicated to producing a replacement for the gnome onscreen keyboard (gok).

http://live.gnome.org/Caribou

Ted Gould from Canonical's User Experience team was there to discuss the issues and availability of the keyboard and weather caribou would dock, if it was themeable and if it could support existing keyboard layout files.

Answer (score 1):

try out [florence virtual keyboard](http://florence.sourceforge.net/) works like a charm